# empty function but segmentation fault in function parameter

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

my C program has type definition of a stack like this :

```
typedef struct {
    char T[MaxEl+1][MAX_CHAR];
    address TOP;
    boolean alive;//ignore this
} Stack;
```

and create a function:

```
void expandP(Stack stack[],int i,char input[]) {//variable stack is array of Stack
    ..

    Stack temp;
    CreateEmpty(&temp);
    ..
    copyStack(&temp,stack[i]);
}

void CreateEmpty(Stack *S) {
    Top(*S) = Nil;
    isAlive(*S) = false;
}

void copyStack(Stack* out,Stack in) {

}
```

it gives error segmentation fault when running and no warning when compile

Comment: Please post actual code that would demonstrate the problem. Also, the debugger is your friend. If you run your program in it, it will show you where the segfault is occurring.

Comment: what are the values for MaxEl and MAX_CHAR? may be you're allocating too much on the stack.

Comment: Specifically what causes the segmentation fault? Have you inspected your variables in a debugger?

Comment: the problems disappeared after i try the solution from B Mitch

Comment: @Donotalo, MaxEl and MAX_CHAR is already defined somewhere in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Stack in` a pointer

```
void copyStack(Stack* out, const Stack *in) {
```

And then call it like so:

```
copyStack(&temp,&stack[i]);
```

Comment: wooww,this fixes the problem, why is it so?

Comment: Something in your `struct` can't be copied like you would an `int`, so you need to pass a pointer to it.  Honestly, I've never passed a `struct` in any way other than via a pointer, but I'm doing it in `C` and it looks like you are using a derivative.